# Полиморфизм в реляционных БД. Возможно ли?

Tags: sql, база-данных, полиморфизм

Есть база данных (postgresql), содержащая три таблицы - 
Люди (ID, Имя, Фамилия, Отчество, Наименование), 
Организации (ID, Наименование, Адрес, Расчетный счет), 
Автомобили (ID, Марка, Модель, Пробег, Владелец). 
Суть проблемы:
Необходимо создать связи между автомобилями и владельцами. Владельцем автомобиля может быть как человек (запись в таблице Люди), так и организация (запись в таблице Организации).
Вопрос:
Каким образом можно осуществить данную связь? Может ли внешний ключ быть полиморфным и, следовательно, каким образом во время JOIN узнать с какой таблицей объединятся(как хранить информацию о типе во внешнем ключе)?
PS:
Заранее извиняюсь за, возможно, глупый вопрос, и прошу учесть, тот факт, что с SQL и РБД как таковыми только познакомился, и есть острая необходимость решить вышеуказанную проблему в крайне короткий срок.
**Update:**
В первой версии вопроса не указал общее поле - Наименование - в случае если Владелец - человек, его Наименование - например, Иванов И.И.
В качестве примера приведу вымышленный код, думаю так будет понятней:

```
SELECT Авто.Марка, Авто.Модель, Наименование FROM Авто
INNER JOIN Авто.Внешний_ключ_владельца.Таблица ON Авто.Внешний_ключ_владельца.ID = Авто.Владелец.ID
```

И возможный результат:
"Daewoo" "Nexia" "Иванов. И.И."
"Ford" "Focus" "ООО ТОРГОПТ"
"Schevrolet" "Camaro" "Сидоров С.В."

Comment: А вы не думали хранить связи в отдельной таблице, с указанием типа связи?

Comment: Я бы ввел четвертую таблицу "Субъекты права", которыми могут быть как люди так и организации. И в ней бы велись ID для людей и организаций, с указанием типа и возможно каких то общих атрибутов, а ID в таблицах людей и организаций бы брался от туда. и фореджен бы смотрел туда со всех трех ваших таблиц. Если это сложно с точки зрения переделок в системе, можно просто сделать в автомобилях 2 поля - одно смотрит на людей другое на юрлиц. и тригер на таблицу, который не позволяет одновременно двум полям быть со значениями

Comment: Вот, видите, у людей и юрлиц у вас уже появился общий атрибут - наименование. Значит новая сущность "Субъекты права" напрашивается. Кстати, в postgress есть наследование таблиц, не знаю, что это и с чем едят но может то что надо

Comment: Спасибо, по вашей наводке нашел материал по наследованию в PostgreSQL, очень полезная информация, особенно в условиях нехватки времени. Думаю то, что нужно. Жаль ваш комментарий нельзя пометить как ответ.

Comment: Я могу его и ответом написать. Я про наследование сам почитал, мне не понравилось. Оно конечно какие то задачи с выборкой облегчит, но по факту insert надо делать явно и в родителя и в наследника. Так что с точки зрения инсерта подход такой же как с не наследованными таблицами "Субъекты права"<-организации/люди

Comment: @Mike, ну так и пишите как ответ... И Вам плюс, и у на один закрытый вопрос :):):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура данных должна быть такой, чтобы запросы по ней были максимально простыми. Если вам в вашем запросе нужно только Наименование от владельца, то в разделении людей и организаций нет никакого смысла. Это должна быть одна таблица Владельцы. Дополнительные поля могут быть как в той же таблице, так и в дочерних типа "данные юрлиц"/"данные физлиц". Все зависит от запросов, сравните ваш вариант:

```
select cars.*, persons.fullname from cars 
  join persons on cars.owner = persons.id and cars.isorg = 0
union all
select cars.*, orgs.fullname from cars 
  join orgs on cars.owner = orgs.id and cars.isorg = 1
```

и запрос с одной таблицей:

```
select cars.*, owners.fullname from cars join owners on cars.owner = owners.id
```

Если вам понадобятся все дополнительные поля в этом запросе (надо еще придумать как их красиво выводить в одной таблице) вы получите одни и те же данные: будут null для людей в адресе и расчетном счете, и null для фио для организаций.

Если вы планируете более сложную логику запросов (которую вы в вопросе не указали) то идите от нее. И идите путем простоты.

Comment: Действительно, предложенный вами вариант является наиболее логичным. Постепенно приходит осознание того, как должны проектироваться реляционные базы данных. По инерции объектного мышления трудно усваивается плоская табличная модель - в голове базовые классы, наследование и полиморфизм.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил добавить в таблицу Автомобили поле "Тип Владельца", и в нем хранить лишь два варианта: "чел" и "орг". В зависимости от содержимого этого поля связывать поле Владелец либо с таблицей Людей, либо Организаций.